# What is it called when your Mac doesn't fully crash?

Tags: terminology

What is it called when an app crashes and it ends up logging you out, without restarting your computer?  The computer never fully turns off because the `/tmp` fold doesn't get reset.

Comment: I'd call it *user(-)land crash*

Answer (score 2):

This is most often caused by the WindowServer process crashing. However, there's not really a name for this specific type of crash.

On iOS it corresponds to the Springboard crashing, which is then named "springboarding".

However, no such name exists in common use for macOS.

Answer (score -1):

The german word would be "neustartunmöglichweilnekernerweiterunghängt" ;)

I english I'd call it time for

```
(sudo kextunload *; sudo shutdown -h now)
```

Comment: Not really - the German sentence means something completely different. The literal translation is "Reboot not possible because of hanging kernel extension" - this is definitely not the case here. Also the command you've given is not appropriate for the scenario in the question.

Comment: Well.. if it's not a kernel extension hanging, the shut down will execute after a timeout because the system will force terminate the application that crashed. If it doesn't, you have a hanging kernel extension - hence the name. My experience is that logging in to the mac by ssh and executing the command that I wrote down will solve the problem. Try it out and up or downvote when it works or not. If "this is definitely not the case here", then what is?

Comment: You're totally off? Your suggestions does not have anything to do with the question? The user does not have a hanging machine, he does not want to shut down the machine, and he doesn't need to login via SSH as he's already logged in on the interactive, graphical side of things. He's just asking if there's a name for the phenomenon that WindowServer crashed and you're logged out. You can just login afterwards.

Comment: Ah, got it. And that logs you out?!

Comment: Yes, it does...